# Как переносить строчки на wordpress в функции the_content()

Tags: wordpress, функции

Короче, я добавил поcты к сайту с текстом, но там где выводится контент поста текст не переносится на следующую строку и увеличивает размер блока.

Как исправить эту ошибку?

Версткой не получается выправить, потому что текст просто выходит за рамки блока, помогите

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы ничего не делали с фильтром the_content, то все должно быть хорошо. Но в целом за переносы отвечает функция wpautop

Comment: Спасибо вам большое, данная функция помогла!

Comment: На самом деле вам лучше разобраться, почему у вас не отрабатывает the_content. wpautop прикреплен к фильтру the_content по умолчанию

Answer (score 0):

Есть специальная функция wpautop